# Video conversion flow for HLS (m3u8) with Django and CloudFront

Tags: django, ffmpeg, django-rest-framework, boto3, amazon-cloudfront

I was trying to find out how to do something like HLS to prevent BEGINNERS from hacking my content, and I think I got it a little after researching all night.

Currently, I know I have to do the following:

- install ffmpeg
- convert the video after upload (I think it will be this way)
- send the files, and offer the link to the .m3u8 file (which will be together with the .ts files)

The question now is:

- I don't know yet how to set the cloudfront
- I don't know if I will need to use signed urls / cookies
- I don't know how to create the video conversion stream (I must use
  ffmpeg to convert and create the files, and then use the aws Python
  SDK to upload to AWS, and then change the video field, or even even
  delete the original video after upload, maybe in the save method?)

Comment: I highly recommend you use a service like mux.com, or similar, for media processing and signed URLs.

Comment: @szatmary i know that services that offers this solutions, but i dont have money and aws is low cost

Comment: I believe you underestimate the cost of AWS, and the value of your time. Ffmpeg takes a lot of CPU. Many services are pay as you go and have startup credits. And if the traffic is very low, so is the bill. And if the traffic grows, then it would be worth the time to invest in a cheaper solution.

Comment: @szatmary yeah, but if traffic grows, probably i will have money to pay service like vimeo (that is cheaper than mux, i think)

Comment: Hi @marcossouza, if you got solution please suggest what you have used?